# Getting the value of an int array at an index in c#

Tags: c#

I want to get the value of my integer array, at an index. The GetValue method refuses the int type.

What am I doing wrong?

```
return locX.GetValue(Ind);
```

Ind is an integer, locX is declared like: `public int[] locX;`

I know I am doing SOMETHING wrong. Sorry for the noobiness of this question, I am kinda new to c#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try `locX[Ind]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
return locX[Ind];
```